# How to pass dynamic arguments to Structuremap when constructing a new type?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

There are cases in my app where my repositories require passing different arguments to constructors of the concrete types. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
var arg = (x == y) ? z : a;
ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository>(arg);
```

Where the argument can only be constructed at the time of creating the Repository instance depending on some condition.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Steven also says, I think that if possible you should let the class that needs the dependency (that has a dynamic argument) take a factory as a parameter so that you can control the creation from the consumer.

With structure map there is built in support for this so that you don't have build a factory class.

Let the consumer take a Func as a ctor argument and create the repository (dependency) by invoking the Func with the argument:

```
public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer(Func<ArgumentType, IRepository> repositoryFactory)
    {
      _repositoryFactory = repositoryFactory;
    }

    public void CallRepository()
    {
       ArgumentType arg = (x == y) ? z : a;
       var repository = _repositoryFactory(arg);
       repository.GetById(...);
    }
}
```

In the configuration for structure map, you can configure the func:

```
For<Func<ArgumentType, IRepository>>().Use( arg => new Repository(arg));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work:

```
var arg = (x == y) ? z : a;
ObjectFactory.With("argumentName").EqualTo(arg).GetInstance<IRepository>();
```

Comment: Can this be done after having configured concrete types in Structuremap? or it must be done during the configuration?

Comment: @Am - it's done after configuration, when you get an instance from the container. However you should try to avoid this and use Dependency Injection instead of Service Location if possible.

Comment: @Am - @PHeiberg is correct on both accounts. It is done after configuration, and I would also recommend using Dependency Injection as shown in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `IRepositoryFactory` and register and resolve that instead of resolving the `IRepository`. This will save you from having to call the container directly from within your application. That should be [prevented](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) at all cost.